# Oracle Audit Trail to get the list of columns which got updated in last transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Consider a table(Student) under a schema say Candidates(NOT DBA):

> **Student**
> {RollNumber : VARCHAR2(10),
> Name : VARCHAR2(100),
> CLass : VARCHAR2(5),
> **...
> ...
> ...**
> }

Let us assume that the table already contains some valid data.

I executed an update query to modify the name and class of the Student table

```
UPDATE STUDENT SET Name = 'ASHWIN' , CLASS = 'XYZ' 
WHERE ROLLNUMBER = 'AQ1212'
```

Followed by another update query in which I am updating some other fields

```
UPDATE STUDENT SET Math_marks = 100 ,PHY_marks , CLASS = 'XYZ' 
WHERE ROLLNUMBER = 'AQ1212'
```

Since I modified different columns in two different queries. I need to fetch the particular list of columns which got updated in last transaction. I am pretty sure that oracle must be maintaining this in some table logs which could be accessed by DBA. But I don't have the DBA access.

All I need is a the list of columns that got updated in last transaction under schema **Candidates** I **DO NOT** have the DBA rights

Please suggest me some ways.

**NOTE** : Here above I mentioned a simple table. But In actual I have got 8-10 tables for which I need to do this auditing where a key factor lets say ROLLNUMBER acts a foreign key for all other tables. Writing triggers would be a complex for all tables. So please help me out if there exists some other way to fetch the same.

Comment: Do you really mean "transaction" or "statement"?  One transaction is composed of many statements.  Both updates could have been in the same transaction.  What does "last transaction" mean to you?  The last transaction in the current session?  The last statement in the current session?  Or are you really going across all sessions?  It sounds like you need some sort of auditing enabled-- you don't want to scan transaction logs for this sort of thing.  Perhaps a history table where the prior version of the row is written via a trigger.

Comment: If you would had created your table with "ROWDEPENDENCIES", then its possible to track those rows which has been updated. When you create a table with ROWDEPENDENCIES, you will see the new rowscn pseudo-column. The ora_rowscn provides the System Change Number (SCN) associated with each individual row in a table when it was read. The column provides SCN (System Change Number) when last DML was executed on block or row level for a table . SCN system change number can be easily translated as timestamp using function SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @Raj_Te - That tells you roughly when a row was updated (there are issues with that but it's probably close enough for most purposes).  That doesn't tell you which columns were updated which is what this question is all about.

Comment: @JustinCave..Agreed..also there is no way rather than creating a trigger or some history table we can achieve what OP needs. Atmost he can know if a row is getting updated and thats what I tried to convey.

Comment: @R@JustinCave .. I wish to do this for each update statement.(going across all sessions) Apart from trigger or history table is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I am pretty sure that oracle must be maintaining this in some table logs which could be accessed by DBA."

Actually, no, not be default. An audit trail is a pretty expensive thing to maintain, so Oracle does nothing out of the box. It leaves us to decide what we what to audit (actions, objects, granularity) and then to switch on auditing for those things.

The Oracle requires DBA access to enable the built-in functionality, so that may rule it out for you anyway.

Auditing is a very broad topic, with lots of things to consider and configure. The Oracle documentation devotes a big chunk of the Security manual to Auditing. Find the [Introduction To Auditing here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG340). For monitoring updates to specific columns, what you're talking about is Fine-Grained Audit. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_config.htm#GUID-B706FF6F-13A6-4944-AFCB-29971F5076FD).

---

> "I have got 8-10 tables ... Writing triggers would be a complex for all tables."

Not necessarily. The triggers will all resemble each other, so you could build a code generator using the data dictionary view USER_TAB_COLUMNS to customise some generic boilerplate text.

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail?

"Not necessarily. The triggers will all resemble each other, so you could build a code generator using the data dictionary view USER_TAB_COLUMNS to customise some generic boilerplate text."